# How do I capture an iframe location url before it is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iFrame, not controlled by me, that has an initial known source url.  As links within the iframe are clicked, the url and content changes, but I want to capture that location change before it loads, and possibly even interrupt that load.

I know I can capture an iframe's location data like so:

```
$('iframe').on('load',function() { var location = this.contentWindow.location.href; }
```

but is there a way capture the location before it loads, either with jQuery (preferred) or raw javascript?

Comment: Is the URL being added dynamically at all? Eg, will $('iframe').attr('src') work?

Comment: The content in the iframe changes dynamically, yes, so the initial source attribute is of no use unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to find data from the content of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no widely supported way to monitor an iframe for `.src` changes.  Some versions of IE have a propertyChanged event, but other browsers do not support that.

If the links that can change the iframe `.src` are known and they are accessible (not in a cross domain iframe), then you could just add your own click handlers on those links and check the iframe `.src` after the default click is processed.  Depending upon the details of the page, you could either just check on your own event handler or you might need to set a short timer and check after the other event handler runs.

Comment: The initial src is known... I need to capture dynamic changes as the user navigates the content with links within the iframe.  I updated my question to be more clear.  Thanks.

Comment: @Inator - OK, I changed my answer based on the new info.